# How to make main content in the middle of the page and remove white gaps?

Tags: html, css, whitespace, removing-whitespace

Please help, I need the white space on the right bar gone and the position of the main content placed at the middle of the page.

What should I do? Any suggestion?

This is my site : http://www.plebonline.co.uk

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #ea730b;
}

.clock {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 18px;
  display: block;
}

.leftbar {
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: -5000px;
  padding-bottom: 5000px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rightbar {
  float: right;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: -5000px;
  padding-bottom: 5000px; 
  overflow: hidden;
}

.maincontent {
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="wip.html">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="wip.html">Notes</a></li>
  <li><a href="wip.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="wip.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li style="float:right" class="clock" id="clock"></li>
  <script>
    var today = new Date();
    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML=today;
  </script>
</ul>

<div class="leftbar"></div>

<div class="maincontent"></div>

<div class="rightbar"></div>
```

Comment: What white space? Content seems to be in the middle and you seem to have a no white space between left bar, content and right bar

Comment: The main content seem to overlap with the right bar. @AlexandruSeverin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a div tag close without opening that may be causing the problem.

Change:

```
<div class="leftbar"></div>

<div class="maincontent"></div>

</div>
<div class="rightbar"></div>
```

To:

```
 <div class="leftbar"></div>

    <div class="maincontent"></div>

    <div class="rightbar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you didn't put your rightbar and leftbar in any div. In my code here, I remove the right and left bar. You can adjust the code if you want them back.

It's better to add some container to hold all of your element. As you notice the header and the maincontent is inside the div class `.container`.

Hope this help.

```
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height: 100%;

/* 
* The container which hold the header and the main content 
*/
.container {
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    height:1200px;
    background:#333;
    }

/* 
* Header which contain your menu and date 
*/
.header {
    width:100%;
    }

/* 
* The main content of your site 
*/
.maincontent {
    width:80%;
    max-width:1000px;
    background-color: #fff;
    float:left;
    left:50%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left:-500px;
    position: absolute;
    }

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    }

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color: #ea730b;
}

.clock {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 16px 18px;
    display: block;
}

</style>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="wip.html">Projects</a></li>
  <li><a href="wip.html">Notes</a></li>
  <li><a href="wip.html">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="wip.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li style="float:right" class="clock" id="clock"></li>
  <script>
    var today = new Date();
    document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML=today;
  </script>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div  class="maincontent">
<h1>This is the content</h1>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: how do I make it so it main content fills between the bars. thought I would ask as you are a css wizard